# Replacing values in specific variable for specific rows

Tags: stata

I have a data frame in Stata that has an ID variable with some rows missing id values. I want to systematically assign values to these rows with missing values by assigning ids that increase in value. For example, this is my data frame now:

| id | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Amy | Seattle |
|  | James | Oakland |
|  | Fred | New York |
| 003 | John | Denver |
| 004 | David | Miami |
| 005 | Mary | Chicago |

I would like code that would allow me to fill in the id rows that are blank with numbers that increase in ascending order so that I have a data frame that looks like this:

| id | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Amy | Seattle |
| 002 | James | Oakland |
| 003 | Fred | New York |
| 004 | John | Denver |
| 005 | David | Miami |
| 006 | Mary | Chicago |

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please use `dataex` for a data example as explained in the `stata` tag wiki.  Otherwise some key details about your data are unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with your data example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str5 id str8(name city)
""    "Amy"   "Seattle" 
""    "James" "Oakland" 
""    "Fred"  "New York"
"003" "John"  "Denver"  
"004" "David" "Miami"   
"005" "Mary"  "Chicago" 
end

gen str3 newid = strofreal(_n, "%03.0f")

list, sep(0)

     +--------------------------------+
     |  id    name       city   newid |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |         Amy    Seattle     001 |
  2. |       James    Oakland     002 |
  3. |        Fred   New York     003 |
  4. | 003    John     Denver     004 |
  5. | 004   David      Miami     005 |
  6. | 005    Mary    Chicago     006 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

I have deliberately not overwritten your identifier `id`, which should not be done unless you are absolutely sure that it is what you want.

Also, you showed a blank in your question for the identifier in the first three observations ("rows" is spreadsheet-speak!), and leading zeros otherwise, which together strongly imply that it is a string variable. Stata tends be to more flexible when an identifier is numeric, easy enough in this case using `destring`.

Comment: Thank you! and can you explain what this code is doing? like how does this code know that it needs to add the leading zeros?

Comment: `_n` is the observation number in the current sort order. `help strofreal()` to see what that function does. `help generate` to see what that command does.